# Why does sizeof(*value) returns different value than sizeof(value) in c++

Tags: c++, sizeof

I'm curious about this one:

```
int main()
{
    int a[7];
    std::cout << "Length of array = " << (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)) << " - " << sizeof(a) << " - " << sizeof(*a) << std::endl;
}
```

Returns

```
Length of array = 7 - 28 - 4
```

So my question is: Why do I have to use `(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a))` to receive the right size, and why does `sizeof(*a)` returns `4`, but `sizeof(a)` returns `28`?

Comment: Because `a` and `*a` are different things with different type with different sizes.

Comment: Got that, thanks. But why doing `(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a))` gives us the right size of the array? And how comes they return that number, and nothing else?

Comment: Note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site. There must be only one question per question.

Comment: @lmaosamoara `*a` is the same as `a[0]`. Then `sizeof(a[0])` gives you the size of one element, while `sizeof(a)` gives you the size of the entire array. Their ratio is the number of elements.

Comment: If you work out what `a` and `*a` is, you should be able to figure out the answer yourself. Just ask yourself: what is `a`? what is `*a`? What does each one mean?

Comment: Because, when `a` is an array,  `sizeof(a)` gives the size of the array in total, whereas `sizeof(*a)` gives the size of the array element.    Arrays are specified as being a set of contiguous elements, all of the same type.   So `sizeof(a)` is the size of an array of seven `int`, and `sizeof(*a)` is the size of an `int`.   This means `sizeof(a) == 7 * sizeof(*a)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(a)` returns `28` because you have 7 elements in the array, and each element is 4 bytes long.

`sizeof(*a)` returns `4` because `*a` dereferences the first element in the array (an integer) which is 4 bytes long.

Thus, `sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a) == 28/4 == 7`

EDIT:
You shouldn't make a habit of finding the length of an array this way in c++. It is much better to keep another variable around which stores the length of the array. `sizeof` is computed at compile-time with fixed-length arrays. If you call `sizeof` on a variable length array, it will usually return 8 as this is the size of a pointer (on 64 bit systems). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838497/what-is-the-cost-of-sizeof) for more information on this.

Comment: You can use `std::size` to get the number of elements in an array.

Comment: Since variable length arrays do not exist in standard C++, there's no need to worry about how to manage them. And note that 8 is certainly not "the size of a pointer"; it might be on the system you're using, but there is no requirement of any particular size, and the sizes of pointers vary depending on the hardware an OS (if any). Same thing for "an integer ... is four bytes long".

Answer (score 2):

`a`, and `*a` have different type; `int[7]` and `int` respectively (ignoring possible reference as l-value).

We have:

- `sizeof(a[0])` = `sizeof(*a)` = `sizeof (int)`
- `sizeof(a)` = `sizeof (int[7])` = `7 * sizeof (int)`
- `sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)` = [`std::extent`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent)`<int[7]>::value` = 7

It appears that, for your configuration, `sizeof(int) == 4`.

Answer (score 0):

The name of an array decays into a pointer to the first element.

```
*a == a[0]
*(1+a) == a[1]
```

And so on.

So, an integer pointer is 4 bytes long, just like an int variable.

On the other hand, the `a` array is an integer array of length 7, so the overall size is `7 * 4 = 28`

Comment: Nothing here has to do with pointers though, so I'm a bit confused with the statement _"So an integer pointer is 4 bytes long just like an int variable."_ A pointer isn't necessarily 4 bytes long (at least not on a modern 64-bit OS). I think it's better to say something like _"So the integer is 4 bytes in size (in this case)."_

Comment: Ted is correct. The `*a` is a de-reference. So it is an integer literal... thus 4 bytes.

Comment: "*The name of an array decays into a pointer*" Except `sizeof(a)` in OP's question is one of the cases where the array name does *not* decay into a pointer. See [Exceptions to array decaying into a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752978/exceptions-to-array-decaying-into-a-pointer).

Answer (score 0):

`a` decays to a pointer when it is passed to a function, used in an operator, or pretty much used like a variable in any way. `*a` is referring to what the decayed pointer points to. In other words, `a` decays to an `int*` which points to the first value in `a`, while `*a` is an `int`, which is why `sizeof` is returning different sizes with the two data types.

Comment: "`a` *is an* `int*`" This is *not* true for `sizeof(a)` which is part of OP's question.

Comment: Ah, I worded it incorrectly. I meant to say `a` decays to an `int*` that points to the first value in `a`, but I wanted to write it concisely.

Answer (score 0):

By the statement `int a[7]`, you are declaring an array of integers of size 7 (Only 7 integer elements can be stored here).
If you use the statement `sizeof(a)`, you get the ***size** of a*. As you probably may know, it is `7 x 4`. (Why 4? Because the size of an integer is 4 bytes). Therefore, if you need to get the *real* size of the array (i.e. the number of elements), you must divide it with the size of `int`.

> Why do I have to use `(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a))` to receive the right size, and why does `sizeof(*a)` returns 4, but `sizeof(a)` returns 28?

To answer this, you must be aware that the array name is actually a pointer to the 1st element of the array (i.e. In this case, it points at `a[0]`.) So, what is `a[0]`? It is an integer right? You can think of `sizeof(*a)` as `sizeof(int)`.
Since `sizeof(int)` returns `4`, so will `sizeof(*a)`.
The reason why you get 7 (the correct answer) is because:
`sizeof(a) = 7 * 4`,
`sizeof(*a) = 4`, therefore
`(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)) = 7`.

Comment: "The size of an integer is 4 bytes" -- on your system, perhaps. That is not required, and it is not true on many hardware/OS combinations. An `int` must be at least 2 bytes.